# How to theme drupal entityforms

Tags: entities

I have created an entityform "Submit your proposal"(Machine name: submit_your_proposal). I would like to theme this form as per my site theme.

I gogled, but didn't find the exact result.

The form fields are given below (in following order Label, Machine name, Field type, Field widget)

Program name, field_pf_program_name, Text, Text field

Email,  field_pf_email, Text, Text field

Organizers details, field_pf_organizers_details, Field collection, Embedded (Field limit is unlimited which gives "Add another item" button)

Proposed duration, field_pf_proposed_duration, Text, Text field

Possible dates, field_pf_possible_dates, Date, Pop-up calendar

Upload your proposal, field_pf_upload_your_proposal, File, File

Organizers details (MAchine name: field_pf_organizers_details) given above is a "Field collection" which contains following fields,

Name, field_pf_organizers_details_name, Text, Text field

Affiliation, field_pf_organizers_details_affi, Text, Text field

Email, field_pf_organizers_details_em, Text, Text field

Please guide me how to create a custom theme for entityform

Thank you

Comment: You won't get a fully-fledged guide here. Just some hints on how to achieve what you are trying to do. Unfortunately listing the fields here doesn't say anything on why you can't implement according CSS styles with your theme. So please elaborate on what exactly can't be styled with your entity forms, or what your special design requirements are?

Comment: Organizers details field (Machine name: field_pf_organizers_details) is a "Field collection" which contains following fields;

Name (field_pf_organizers_details_name), Affiliation( field_pf_organizers_details_affi), Email (field_pf_organizers_details_em); 
these fields appear as a stack and I want these 3 fields in table rows with their label as table header and "Add another item" button should create row with these three fields.

I got the success in changing the name of "Add another item" button to "Add Organizer".